# Making Cupriavidus metallidurans in laboratory?

Tags: bacteriology, genomics

This is probably a stupid question but would it be possible to 'make' *Cupriavidus metallidurans*? And if so how? I'am guessing it wouldn't be possible without the use of expensive equipment for genome sequencing.

Comment: What do you mean by "make"? It is not possible to synthesize living organisms *de novo*. Also, according to Wikipedia, the genome has already been sequenced.

Comment: ok thank you my question then is where can I 'find' them?

Comment: I would expect places with high heavy metal concentration. Don't expect to go swabbing some tailings pond and get a viable, pure culture.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2168447/ They found a strain in "the sludge of a zinc decantation tank in Belgium that was contaminated with high concentrations of several heavy metals."

Comment: Wouldn't I be able to just buy a sample and then create more from those?

Comment: Potentially. This species may be hard to find and I don't expect many distributors would sell to private individuals.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy *Cupriavidus metallidurans* from various culture collections.

See these links below:

- [Cupriavidus metallidurans (Goris et al. 2001) Vandamme and Coenye 2004 - DSMZ](https://www.dsmz.de/catalogues/details/culture/DSM-2839.html)
- [Cupriavidus metallidurans (Goris et al.) Vandamme and Coenye (ATCC® 43123™) - ATCC](https://www.lgcstandards-atcc.org/products/all/43123.aspx?geo_country=gb)

As canadianer has already explained, it will be next to impossible to "find" a pure, viable culture out there in the environment.